# PHP autoload namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I want to autoload my classes putting only the namespace + the filename.

**Example:**

**directories skeleton:**

```
\var\www
  |_ foo
  |  |_ A.php
  |  |_ B.php
  |  
  |_ index.php
```

**A.php:**

```
<?php

namespace foo\A;

class A {

   private $a;

   public function __construct($a) {
       $this->a = $a;
   }

}
```

**B.php:**

```
<?php

namespace foo\B;

use foo\A;

class B extends A {

    private $b;

    public function __construct($a, $b) {
        parent::__construct($a);
        $this->b = $b;
    }   

}
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php

use foo\B;

define('ROOT', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$b = new B('s', 2);

function __autoload($classname) {
    $namespace = substr($classname, 0, strrpos($classname, '\\'));
    $namespace = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname);
    $classPath = ROOT . str_replace('\\', '/', $namespace) . '.php';

    if(is_readable($classPath)) {
        require_once $classPath;
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the class A and B I declare the namespace with the classname, and when I use it I print the variables of the __autoload and are correct, bur when call the constructor, don't find the class.

**error:**

```
Fatal error: Class 'foo\A' not found in /var/www/foo/B.php on line 7
```

If I only instantiate A, and I don't use B, the problem is the same.

I need to do it like this, because I want that in class B, you can't use A if you don't put the use statement, to do it more strict.

I don't now if you understand my problem for my explanation, but thanks anyway for any suggestion!!

PD: Sorry for my english skills.

Comment: YOur namespace declarations are wrong. If you want to archive what you pictured in that tree, it has to be `namespace foo` for both classes - no classnames in namespace declarations.

Comment: I know, but I want that the namespace that I put is with the classname, to be more strict, because if I don't do it, I can use classes from the same namespace without importing with use statement.

Comment: The way you're doing it, the class names are actually `foo\A\A` and `foo\B\B`. SO the classloader is looking for the files `ROOT/A/A.php` and `ROOT/B/B.php`. DO they exist?

Comment: Yes, this is what happens, so there are any way to import only the class like java, and not the fully namespace?

Comment: you mean like `use foo\B\B as B`? ;)

Comment: More or less. If in the class I put the namespace foo, in index I don't have any problem, because if I use A, there are a error. But if in B.php I don't put "use foo\A", A is readable because A is in the same namespace than B, and this is that I don't want. But I suppose what I want is impossible. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Your code should be that in classes :

**A.php**

```
<?php

namespace foo;

class A {

   private $a;

   public function __construct($a) {
       $this->a = $a;
   }

}
```

**B.php**

```
<?php

namespace foo;

class B extends A {

    private $b;

    public function __construct($a, $b) {
        parent::__construct($a);
        $this->b = $b;
    }   

}
```

Comment: Exactly this. It's just the namespace-declarations that are wrong, so your autoloader doesn'T find the files it'S looking for. (see my comment on the question)

Comment: I want that the importing namespaces be like java, that you only import the class and not the package/namespace.