# Namespace and autoload error, How do I use PHP namespaces with autoload correctly?

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to autoload to use namespace in my classes but i get a error in the index.php

```
Error: Fatal error: Class 'foo\B' not found ...
```

Example:

directories skeleton:

```
  \var\www
      |_ foo
      |  |_ A.php
      |  |_ B.php
      |  
      |_ view
      |  |_ index.php
```

A.php

```
<?php

namespace foo;

class A {

   private $a;

   public function __construct($a) {
       $this->a = $a;
   }

}
```

B.php

```
<?php

namespace foo;

use foo\A;

class B extends A {

    private $b;

    public function __construct($a, $b) {
        parent::__construct($a);
        $this->b = $b;
    }   

}
```

And Index.php

```
<?php

use foo\B;

define('ROOT', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$b = new B('s', 2);

function __autoload($classname) {
    $namespace = substr($classname, 0, strrpos($classname, '\\'));
    $namespace = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname);
    $classPath = ROOT . str_replace('\\', '/', $namespace) . '.php';

    if(is_readable($classPath)) {
        require_once $classPath;
    }
}
```

This question is almost the same as this one: [PHP autoload namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942462/php-autoload-namespace) but I include the index.php in other Folder and does not work.

If I put the same project but with the next directories skeleton, I don't get any error.

```
  \var\www
      |_ foo
      |  |_ A.php
      |  |_ B.php
      |  
      |_ index.php
```

**The question is: Why if I put the index.php in a folder does not work?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because the ROOT constant is pointing to `/var/www/view/`, not `/var/www/`. It changes as you move index.php to a different directory.

You might want to take a look at the function [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php). With that you can set multiple root directory definitions. You can then loose the ROOT constant altogether.